# How can I add a specific PHP function to my server's install of PHP

Tags: php, configuration, json

I am running PHP version 5.1.6 currently, but I would have an application which makes pretty heavy use of the `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions, as such, I would like to add these functions to my server's install of PHP (as these functions only ship with PHP versions PHP 5.2 +)

What is the best way of doing this. I'm not too down with the whole Terminal approach so if there was another way that would be great

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Which OS are you using? Why not just update PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to upgrade, use PEAR's [Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON). It works as of PHP 4.3 so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put somewhere in the root of your application a call to a checker function that does [function_exists()](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) for a couple of your needed function and if not stops the execution to prevent unwanted results.